# Graphviz Graph creation noobie Image from java

Tags: java, graphviz

I would like to run my java program, which needs to make a bunch of images of graphs. I have a website, but I do not want the graphviz program to be run everytime someone visits the page, so I am running a scheduled server side java program, that will make the graphs, so that the web page just pics up the images. Now I can't seem to figure it out. I am using spring to query a database to generate info for my graph, and then I make a .dot file. Using a simple text writer. I put the whole graphviz program on my server, how would I go about getting an image from this .dot file. I have done my research and I need to make a

```
  $ -Tpng graphic.dot -o graphic.png
```

type call, but that is a terminal call. And I cant seem to figure it out. Should I be using something like Grappa? How should I go about doing this problem? Should I try to ope the exe and pass that line of code in as a parameter, furthermore where will the image file be created?

Comment: Why don't you simply go for something like JGraph http://www.jgraph.com/? It offers interactivity for free ;)

Comment: Graphviz is supposed to be one of the fastest graph creators, I am making hundreds of graphs with hundreds of nodes in each. All of which need to be done extremely quickly.

Comment: True but in the other hand you will have to create images and send them over the internet to your clients. There is a chance that you will loose all of those gains offered by GraphViz

Comment: That is not true, to generate a graph you need to querry my database, so making an image with one call, and them sending the image out to all the people is more efficient. Then hundreds of database calls, locking up my database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I correctly understood, you'd like to run a command line program from within a java program running regularly on your server.

You may try something along those lines:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("c:\\graphvizbinpath\\dot.exe -Tpng c:\\graphic.dot -o c:\\graphic.png");
```

Of course you'll need to adapt the paths, and the users executing the java program should have the appropriate file system permissions.

Comment: Sorry, something came up, and I had to support some other code. I will be getting back to it tomorrow morning, but I really appreciate the help.